# TcpListener - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

```
        int port = 44344;

        var thread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                TcpListener listener = null;
                try
                {
                    listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
                    listener.Start();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    }
                }
                catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
                { }

                if (listener != null)
                    listener.Stop();
            });
        thread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        socket.Connect("localhost", port);
```

This code fails on the last line with "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" exception, when running on my PC. Any ideas what can be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you call *Connect* before your thread gets the chance to run. Test by adding a Thread.Sleep before calling connect.

Comment: @Eser, unfortunately no. It haven't changed anything.

Comment: And by using `ProtocolType.Tcp`?

Comment: @Eser, no success. too.

Comment: Is that code the real code? Pasting it into LINQPad works. Are there firewalls that block localhost to localhost traffic?!

Comment: I just ran this on my computer, and once I told my firewall to allow access, it ran fine.  Of course there were no communications as there are none in the program, but I did not get an exception either.  I suspect you have a firewall issue as @usr suggested.

Comment: @usr, yes it's the real sample I'm checking. No, I have Windows firewall only and the loopback connection is not blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to create the client socket with an AddressFamily parameter specified:

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
```