# -Solved- Socket Exception - No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm using c# sockets to create a client-server connection on my pc, for now locally, but the exception in the title is the only signal I receive back.

I've already tried disabling the firewall, checking if the port I'm using(51111) is listening(yes) and unticking everything in LAN settings(to avoid proxying), all of them at the same time too.

My code(just temporary test code)

Server Class

> ```
> class Server
> {
>     private Socket listener;
>     public void SocketServer()
>     {
>         int maxBuffer = 1024;
>         Console.WriteLine("LISTENER ENABLED");
>         listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
>         listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 51111));
>         listener.Listen(5);
>         while (true)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("WAITING FOR CONNECTION");
>             Socket socket = listener.Accept();
>             string receivedMessage = string.Empty;
>             while (true)
>             {
>                 byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[maxBuffer];
>                 int bytesReceivedCount = socket.Receive(receivedBytes);
>                 receivedMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, bytesReceivedCount);
>                 if (receivedMessage.IndexOf('\n') > -1)
>                 {
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>                 Console.WriteLine("Message from Client : " + receivedMessage);
>                 string reply = ("Message received!");
>                 byte[] replyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reply);
>                 socket.Send(replyBytes);
>                 socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
>                 socket.Close();
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

Client Class

> ```
> class Client
> {
>     public void SocketClient(string request)
>     {
>         int maxBuffer = 1024;
>         try
>         {
>             IPHostEntry iPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
>             IPAddress address = iPHostEntry.AddressList[0];
>             IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(address, 51111);
>
>             Socket sender = new Socket(address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
>
>             try
>             {
>                 sender.Connect(remoteEP);
>
>                 Console.WriteLine("Connected to " + sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
>
>
>                 byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
>                 int bytesSent = sender.Send(message);
>                 byte[] response = new byte[maxBuffer];
>                 int bytesReceived = sender.Receive(response);
>                 Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, 0, bytesReceived));
>             }
>             catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
>             }
>             catch (SocketException se)
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
>             }
>             catch (Exception e)
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception e)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to set the IP address family? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171574/tcplistener-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-re?rq=1

Comment: Yes. It's in the code I've posted too. Not sure if done properly because I'm new to sockets, but I've copied from examples I've found from googling.

Comment: Check iPHostEntry.AddressList[0];  It may be a IPV6 entry or the loopback 127.0.0.1 which will give errors.  It should be either the IP address of the machine (IPV4) or computer name.  The Net Library automatically gives an error when you use 127.0.0.1 in the Connect method.  Localhost will also give error depending on how the machine Host file is set located in folder : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: Thank you jdweng it worked!
I've checked with a foreach all the Ipadresses and only the second one was an Ipv4. I've changed my code(putting an index of 1 instead of 0) and now it runs perfectly